# Problema ao passar algumas mensagens Json para Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Galera, tenho um formulário que é passada para o meu PHP via Ajax no Jquery e retorna o resultado via Json para o meu console. Segue um trecho do código no PHP.

```
if($tabela == 'setup') {

    if(isset($_POST['nome'])){
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        if(strlen($nome) < 6) {
            $res['resultado'] = "inv";
            $res['campo'] = "nome";
            $res['mensagem'] = "Nome muito curto";
        } else {
            $sql = "UPDATE professores SET nome='$nome' WHERE idprofessor = $meuid";
        }
    } else if(isset($_POST['email']) and isset($_POST['telefone'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $sql = "UPDATE professores SET email='$email',telefone='$telefone' WHERE idprofessor = $meuid";
        } else {
            $res['mensagem'] = "E-mail inválido.";
        }

    } else if(isset($_POST['senha_nova'])){
        $res['ok'] = "senha";
        $senha_atual = md5($_POST['senha_atual']);
        $busca_atual = $pdw -> prepare("SELECT senha FROM professores WHERE idprofessor = $meuid AND senha = '$senha_atual'");
        try {
            $busca_atual -> execute();
            $res['resultado'] = "ok";
            $res['mensagem'] = "Dados retornados";
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $res['resultado'] = "erro";
            $res['mensagem'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        if($busca_atual->rowCount < 1) {
            $res['resultado'] = "ok";
        } else {
            $senha_nova = $_POST['senha_nova'];
            $senha_confirma = $_POST['senha_confirma'];
            // comparar senhas
            //$sql = "UPDATE professores SET senha=".md5($senha_nova)." WHERE idprofessor = $meuid";
            $res['sql'] = $sql;
        }
    };
    if($sql) {
        $atualiza = $pdw -> prepare($sql);
        try {
            $atualiza -> execute();
            $res['resultado'] = "ok";
            $res['mensagem'] = "Dados atualizados com sucesso";
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $res['resultado'] = "erro";
            $res['mensagem'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($res);
```

Depois tem o código para executar o update via PDO e o *echo json_encode($res);*

Se o usuário digitar mais de 6 caracteres na caixa de texto, ele executa corretamente e imprime no console log corretamente. Porém se digitar menos não retorna a mensagem de erro, como esperado.

Fiz o teste colocando o formulário diretamente nesta página ajax.php e ele exibe as mensagens corretamente, mas para o Jquery não vai.

Segue código do Jquery

```
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formulario = $(this).attr('name');
    var acao = $(this).attr('action');
    var dados = $(this).serialize();
    $('input.validate').removeClass('invalid');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/geral.php?act='+acao+'&tbl='+formulario,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dados,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.resultado == 'ok') {
                M.toast({html: data.mensagem});
            } else if(data.resultado == 'erro') {
                M.toast({html: "Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar dados."});
                console.log(data.mensagem);
            } else if(data.resultado == 'inv') {
                M.toast({html: data.mensagem});
                $('input.validate#'+data.campo).addClass('invalid');
            }
            console.log(data);
        },
    })

})
```

Dado curioso é que, se eu colocar o SQL no primeiro bloco condicional e digitar menos de 6 caracteres, ele executa a query e imprime no log.

Comment: Você pode colocar seu código completo? Acredito que fique mais fácil de localizar o problema.

Comment: O site não está deixando eu postar o código inteiro, informando ser muito longo.

Comment: Consegui editar a postagem original e colocar o código completo.
Ignore essa parte do e-mail e senha, pois ainda não estão prontas. Se bem que ele também não exibe a mensagem de erro se a senha estiver errada..

Answer (score -1):

Dentro do `if()` que verifica se o nome está curto, também vai um

```
echo json_encode($res)
```

Comment: Já fiz isso e não resolveu. Inclusive meu echo está no final do código e pega todas as demais mensagens.

Comment: então passa o código inteiro pra gnt poder ver o que vc já fez e qual o problema

Comment: O site não me deixa postar o código inteiro, dizendo ser muito longo.

Comment: mas passa pelo menos essa parte

Comment: Consegui editar a postagem original e colocar o código completo.
Ignore essa parte do e-mail e senha, pois ainda não estão prontas. Se bem que ele também não exibe a mensagem de erro se a senha estiver errada..

Comment: cade os retornos do json?

Comment: Acabei esquecendo de colocar junto, pois tem outros códigos irrelevantes. Mas fica depois do fechamento da última chave.

Comment: Entendi, mas se vc colocar o echo la dentro da chave do erro ainda sim não da?

Comment: Exatamente. Mesmo assim não funciona. É realmente muito estranho.

Comment: Consegui resolver. Era só colocar um @ na condicional if($sql), ficando if(@$sql)